# Full Adder illustration in book incorrect?

Tags: assembly

A Full Adder illustrated in Beginners Guide to Microprocessors [and thus assembly] by Charles M. Gilmore using 2 XOR gates and 1 AND gate seems a bit odd.

[image: Full Adder]

Everything looks fine until A and B are 1 and 1. When A and B are 1 and 1, the output is 0, and the value which then gets passed into the AND gate to produce the carry will also be 0, which can't be true because the addition of two 1's will render X zero, true, but then the carry is also zero, which is false.

Let's go through all cases:

Let Ci be the carry from a previous addition, both A and B be inputs, X the sum, and Co the carry from the addition of A and B.

Ci = 0, A = 0, B = 1. A and B through a XOR gate produces 1; The addition of 1 and 0 is 1. 1 and 0 through an AND gate is 0, which means there is no carry over, and the 1 and 0 through the second XOR gate means the sum is 1. This is true. Following this mode of thought...

```
 _______________________________
|  Ci  |  A  |  B  |  X  |  Co  |
---------------------------------
   0      0     0     0     0
   1      0     0     1     0
   0      1     0     1     0
   1      1     0     0     1
   0      0     1     1     0
   1      0     1     0     1
   0      1     1     0     0?????
   1      1     1     1     0?????
```

Am I missing something here? 1 and 1 produce 0 in Exclusive Or logic. There can never be a carry when both A and B are 1?

If I perform the following binary addition,you can note how the third column produces 0, but carries over the 1.:

```
100101
001100
------
110001
```

What I am thinking wrong here? Thanks for your time.

Comment: That's indeed wrong, are you sure that's in the book?

Comment: Absolutely it is in the book. Page 57.

Comment: It says it's the third printing of May 1980.

Comment: Maybe they dropped a part of it, this is the start of a well-known FA, missing the "OR (A AND B)" part.